# I want to convert a pic 9(5) comp 3 to pic 9(05) comp using batch sort

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

I want to convert a `comp-3` to `comp` using batch sort. Please help me.

I have tried **PD to ZD** conversion but that’s not working.

Comment: 1) Why the JCL tag - this is a sort problem. JCL cannot do what you want - it simply tells the operating system that you want to exc one or more programs and the resources required.

Comment: 2) How does it not work? Job fails with JCL errors?; job abends?  Job produces the wrong results? What does your data look like? RECFM, LRECL? What do your sort control statements look like? Besides which comp-3 is packed decimal and comp is binary not zoned decimal (ZD).

Comment: Can you provide the control statements you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try using inrec build option

Option=copy
Inrec build=(1, 5,pd, to, =zd, length=9)

Try this. If you are getting error,let me know

Comment: The output is required as the DFSORT equivalent of COMP not zoned decimal, COMP in DFSort erms is BI (I think - I am not going to look up the manual as it is not my problem)

Answer (score 0):

I've shown an example below.

```
//STEP01   EXEC PGM=SORT
//SORTIN   DD *
23456 
12345    
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD *
  INREC FIELDS=(1:1,5,ZD,TO=PD,LENGTH=3)
  SORT FIELDS=(1,3,PD,A)
  OUTREC FIELDS=(1:1,3,PD,TO=BI,LENGTH=4)
/*
```

**Note:**

Usage of `INREC` to convert the readable format to PD in the example shown above is just for representation.

You may try writing the output from the SORT step shown above to an output dataset and subsequently pass it as an input to another SORT step with following control statements. This way you can ensure whether you're able to get back the readable numeric data.

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY
OUTREC FIELDS=(1:1,4,BI,EDIT=(TTTTT))
```